# CefSharp load only specific frame

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

The Control is loading a webpage that consists of 4 frames. The program interacts only with one specific frame of that site. Is it possible to load only that frame and like "pipe" it to the CefSharp Browser Control to display only the content of that frame?

Don't know which code samples could possibly make sense regarding this questions so I won't. Don't be to hard if I do not stick to "conventions" SO community agreed on. BR.

Comment: There's no pipe to concept. How are you identifying the frame? You can load the url in the main frame. An example of the html maybe required.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good hint! I am identifying the frame through a loop over .getFrameNames and saving to to f. The I am trying to load that frames URL to another instance of cefsharp: cb2.Load(cb1.GetBrowser.GetFrame(f).Url) But that site somehow prevents from loading only that frame because cb2 remains just white. Maybe there is nothing I can do about it. Thanks a lot anyway for giving me a good hint!

Comment: If you provide an example of your html and the code you've tried. Shouldn't be anything preventing you from loading just the frame unless they've got some JavaScript that limits the page. You can probably get around that.